# unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range

Tags: cassandra

Had 4 nodes cluster with 2 seeds. Using `cassandra 1.2.5`. Thought of making 2 clusters with 2 nodes with 1 seed in each cluster.

Decommissioned, changed the seeds in cassandra.yaml file and deleted data and commitlog directories and restarted, one nodes started fine and second one showing for both clusters.

```
INFO 10:28:37,241 JOINING: sleeping 30000 ms for pending range setup
INFO 10:29:07,242 JOINING: Starting to bootstrap...
ERROR 10:29:07,324 Exception encountered during startup
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to find sufficient sources for
>   streaming range (5253604194908817102,5256320442405919104]

Answer (score 4):

If all your data was cleared and you are setting up new nodes, you should get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range (5253604194908817102,5256320442405919104]

The exception means you don't have enough data to send across the required ranges, for example, if you had replication factor 1 for a certain keyspace in a 4 node cluster and you remove 2 nodes, you wont be able to stream certain ranges as they are lost with the decommissioned nodes.

From what i understand you are trying to do this:

```
Original Cluster:
Cluster A (x2 seeds) [node1, node2, node3, node4]

New Cluster(s):
Cluster A (x1 seed) [node1, node2] <-- no data
Cluster B (x1 seed) [node1, node2] <-- no data
```

Meaning that you removed 1 seed from the original cluster, and decommissioned 2 nodes. Then the 2 nodes that were decommissioned were added used in their own cluster (cluster B). And for all 4 nodes you removed the data directories / commit logs.

If you did this you shouldn't be streaming any data. This means you probably didn't remove all the data directories. My advice is to use a clean install of C* and just configure `cassandra.yaml` for the new infrastructure of 2 clusters with 1 seed node each.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/var/lib/cassandra/data/system` directory and remove all subdirectory except `%schema%`. Use

```
rm -rf batchlog compaction_history compactions_in_progress hints IndexInfo local NodeIdInfo paxos peer_events peers range_xfers sstable_activity
```

and restart your cassandra node.